# Expand Numpy array within a data frame to own columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks something like this:

| Col A | Col B | keys | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | [key1, key2, key3] | [value1a, value2a, value3a] |
| data | data | [key1, key2, key3] | [value1b, value2b, value3b] |

The "keys" are the same in each row. The "values" differ in each row. "keys" and "values" are both of type Numpy array.

My goal is to use the keys as column names and then assign the values to the cell within that column to look something like this:

| Col A | Col B | key1 | key2 | key3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | value1a | value2a | value3a |
| data | data | value1b | value2b | value3b |
| data | data | value1c | value2c | value3c |
| data | data | value1d | value2d | value3d |

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67912085/how-can-i-expand-a-numpy-arrays-on-a-df-to-their-own-columns), but it seemed to just create a new data frame using a similar logic. I would be looking to expand upon the already-created data frame.

Here's some code to get the data frames created:

```
source_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['data', 'data', np.array(['key1', 'key2']), np.array(['value1a', 'value2a'])],
        ['data', 'data', np.array(['key1', 'key2']), np.array(['value1b', 'value2b'])]
    ],
    columns=['col 1', 'col 2', 'keys', 'values']
)
goal_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['data', 'data', 'value1a', 'value2a'],
        ['data', 'data', 'value1b', 'value2b'],
    ],
    columns=['col 1', 'col 2', 'key1', 'key2']
)
```

Comment: Can you provide **code** to set up the input example? Assuming `df` give the output of `df.to_dict('tight')`

Answer (score 0):

If the keys are the same in all rows you can convert to DataFrame using the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor and [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html), then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to the original dataset:

```
out = (df.drop(columns=['keys', 'values'])
         .join(pd.DataFrame(df['values'].tolist(),
                            columns=df['keys'].iloc[0]))
      )
```

Alternative to modify `df` in place:

```
df[df.pop('keys').iloc[0]] = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('values').tolist())
```

Output:

```
  Col A Col B     key1     key2     key3
0  data  data  value1a  value2a  value3a
1  data  data  value1b  value2b  value3b
2  data  data  value1c  value2c  value3c
3  data  data  value1d  value2d  value3d
```

##### non-identical keys

If the keys were not identical in all rows you could use:

```
out = (df.drop(columns=['keys', 'values'])
         .join(pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(k, v)) for k, v in
                             zip(df['keys'], df['values'])]))
       )
```

Example:

```
# input
  Col A Col B                keys                       values
0  data  data  [key1, key2, key3]  [value1a, value2a, value3a]
1  data  data  [key3, key4, key1]  [value3b, value4b, value1b]

# output
  Col A Col B     key1     key2     key3     key4
0  data  data  value1a  value2a  value3a      NaN
1  data  data  value1b      NaN  value3b  value4b
```

Comment: these seem to kind of work. they are parsing the keys into columns the way that I expect, but are assigning the values from the first row to every row in the data frame

Comment: I just needed to reset_index() and it solved the issue. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @nick glad it worked. Regarding your question, be careful, the provided example doesn't use arrays but strings

Answer (score 0):

I modified mozway's code by introducing functions with documentation to demonstrate the column transposition.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def create_dataframe(df: pd.DataFrame, key_col: str, val_col: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Create a new dataframe with keys and values transposed.

    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): The source dataframe.
        key_col (str): The column name that represents the keys.
        val_col (str): The column name that represents the values.

    Returns:
        pd.DataFrame: A new dataframe with keys and values transposed.
    """
    return (
        df
        .drop(columns=[key_col, val_col])
        .join(pd.DataFrame(
            df[val_col].tolist(),
            columns=df[key_col].iloc[0]
        ))
    )


def update_dataframe(df: pd.DataFrame, key_col: str, val_col: str) -> None:
    """Update the dataframe in-place by transposing keys and values.

    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): The dataframe to be updated.
        key_col (str): The column name that represents the keys.
        val_col (str): The column name that represents the values.

    Returns:
        None
    """
    df[df.pop(key_col).iloc[0]] = pd.DataFrame(df.pop(val_col).tolist())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    source_df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            ['data', 'data', np.array(['key1', 'key2']), np.array(['value1a', 'value2a'])],
            ['data', 'data', np.array(['key1', 'key2']), np.array(['value1b', 'value2b'])]
        ],
        columns=['Col A', 'Col B', 'keys', 'values']
    )

    # Create a new dataframe
    goal_df = create_dataframe(source_df, 'keys', 'values')
    print(goal_df)  # New dataframe

    print(source_df)  # Source is unmodified

    # Modify the dataframe in-place
    update_dataframe(source_df, 'keys', 'values')
    print(source_df)  # Source is updated
```

Output

```
# Copy of Original
# =============================================
  Col A Col B     key1     key2
0  data  data  value1a  value2a
1  data  data  value1b  value2b

# Original
# =============================================
  Col A Col B          keys              values
0  data  data  [key1, key2]  [value1a, value2a]
1  data  data  [key1, key2]  [value1b, value2b]

# Modified Original
# =============================================
  Col A Col B     key1     key2
0  data  data  value1a  value2a
1  data  data  value1b  value2b
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses [df.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and  [df.assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to accomplish the task.

```
df.explode('values', ignore_index=True).assign(**{k:lambda x: x['values'] for k in df['keys'].iloc[0]}).drop(['keys', 'values'], axis=1)
```

output

```
  col 1 col 2     key1     key2
0  data  data  value1a  value1a
1  data  data  value2a  value2a
2  data  data  value1b  value1b
3  data  data  value2b  value2b
```